# AddLast() on one list adding to all lists in an array of lists C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, linked-list

I essentially have the following code:

```
LinkedList<int>[] listOfNumbers = new LinkedList<int>[6];
int[] someNumbers = new int[6];

for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
{
  listOfNumbers[index] = new LinkedList<int>();
}

someNumnbers[0] = 0;
someNumnbers[1] = 1;
someNumnbers[2] = 2;
someNumnbers[3] = 3;
someNumnbers[4] = 4;
someNumnbers[5] = 5;

for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
{
  listOfNumbers[index].AddLast(someNumbers[index]);
}
```

I expect the following report from the object watch tool in Visual Studio after the first pass of the last loop:

```
listOfNumbers[0] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[1] has no elements
listOfNumbers[2] has no elements
listOfNumbers[3] has no elements
listOfNumbers[4] has no elements
listOfNumbers[5] has no elements
```

But instead I'm curiously finding this:

```
listOfNumbers[0] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[1] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[2] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[3] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[4] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[5] has 1 element with value 0
```

When I run the last loop to its completion, I get the following:

```
listOfNumbers[0] has 6 element with values 0,1,2,3,4,5
listOfNumbers[1] has 6 element with values 0,1,2,3,4,5
listOfNumbers[2] has 6 element with values 0,1,2,3,4,5
listOfNumbers[3] has 6 element with values 0,1,2,3,4,5
listOfNumbers[4] has 6 element with values 0,1,2,3,4,5
listOfNumbers[5] has 6 element with values 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Versus what I expect to get:

```
listOfNumbers[0] has 1 element with value 0
listOfNumbers[1] has 1 element with value 1
listOfNumbers[2] has 1 element with value 2
listOfNumbers[3] has 1 element with value 3
listOfNumbers[4] has 1 element with value 4
listOfNumbers[5] has 1 element with value 5
```

My first guess is I've written something incorrect in the syntax, but I can't seem to figure out what. It obviously seems to be applying the AddLast() to every list in the list array on every pass, but I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the code you show for the first `for` loop that initializes the array elements literally exactly as it appears in your running code?

Comment: Yes, that portion of the code is identical. The only place where what I have in the program deviates slightly is that the numbers assigned to the somenumbers[] elements are actually calculated by another method that returns integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you have the same instance of the linked list in each index, if u are actually initialising the linkedlist array as u have shown it it shouldn't be a problem. The same instance means that u instantiated a linked list once into a variable and then assigned that in each of the array index, this would essentially mean that since they are all the same object internally no matter which object u call the addlast method in, it would reflect in each of those items in the array.

Comment: That definitely sounds like what is happening. To make what I'm thinking might be a crucial clarification without violating my NDA:

The values being placed into the integer array are the calculated results of data being obtained from a class object I had instantiated earlier. So something like,

`someNumbers[0] = myClassObject.Calculate_Int();`

Could this be what's causing the mischief behind the scenes? Because the data comes from a class (a reference object), that something screwy's going on with the references to the LinkedLists?

Comment: I am assuming Calculate_Int() is returning a linkedList, if it is returning an integer as the name suggests the problem wouldn't be there as integers are value types and the above behaviour is restricted to reference types. One simple way you can find out if all the array have the same object (not applicable if they are integers) is look at the hash code for each of them (someNumbers[0].GetHashCode()) while debugging, same objects would have the same hash code, unless there is a custom logic for the same (which wouldn't be the case for linkedLists).

Comment: I just verified that the hash codes are all identical, and I traced it to a logic bug a couple lines prior. Many thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making an array of LinkedLists while you'd want to work with just a LinkedList.

Try to initialize it as a single LinkedList and then add the elements.

Give a look to the example of use to the `LinkedList<T>` class provided in the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using one LinkedList would be nice, but sadly I do actually need an array of lists in the context of the program, as they will later have different node values that will then be compared versus each other.

Comment: I just ran the portion of code you provided in your question, and to me, at the end of the loops, I get what your expected result is and not what you instead get.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather try doing like below using two `for` loop. Outer loop is for passing through each list and inner loop is for filling up each list.

```
for(int i=0; i<6;i++)
{
for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
{
  listOfNumbers[i].AddLast(someNumbers[index]);
}
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestion, that would give me each list containing {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} whereas I'm looking for {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5).