# Adding to list overwrites old values

Tags: c#, .net, list, object, data-structures

I am writing a webscraper and want to store each product (object Product) in a `List<Product> list`

```
public static void ScrapeItem(List<string> itemList)
{
    HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
    ScrapedData data = new ScrapedData();

    LinkedList<Product> list = new LinkedList<Product>();
    Product newProduct = new Product();

    for (int j = 0; j < itemList.Count; j++)
    {
        HtmlRequest req = new HtmlRequest(itemList[j]);
        html = req.StartRequest(html);
        newProduct = data.chooseStrategy(new ConcreteStrategyItemA(html));

        Console.WriteLine("###" + newProduct.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("###" + newProduct.Price);

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");

        list.AddLast(newProduct);
        foreach (Product product in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(product.Price);
        }
    }
```

WriteLine on `newProduct` works fine, so each iteration in foreach loop contains a different product (ProductA,ProductB, ProductC). But when i Store this Object to the list in each iteration, the list Contains Only ProductC at the end.

So the list should contain the following at the end:

```
index 0: ProductA 
index 1: ProductB 
index 2: ProductC
```

But its like this:

```
index 0: ProductC 
index 1: ProductC 
index 2: ProductC
```

I am relatively new to C# but in Java, this code should work.

EDIT:
ChooseStrategy looks like this:

```
 public Product chooseStrategy(ScraperStrategy ConcreteStrategy)
        {
            return ConcreteStrategy.startScraping(product);
        }
```

startScraping looks like this:

```
public override Product startScraping(Product product)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConcreteStrategyitemA");

            product.Name = this._html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[6]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/h1")[0].InnerText; // Name xPath

            product.Price = this._html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[6]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]")[0].InnerText; // Price xPath

            return product;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't shared the source of `data.chooseStrategy`, but presumably it's returning the same `Product` object each time?

Comment: As an aside you are instantiating the object before the loop and overwriting the value every iteration. This is an indicator that you do not really understand object orientation and it can introduce weird bugs or give you a false sense of security. 

You should try to read up on object orientation and change `Product newProduct = new Product();` to `Product newProduct;`

Comment: Please [do _not_ add tags to your question's title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/133056).

Comment: In your `chooseStrategy` method, where does `product` come from? It does however look like it returns the same `Product` instead each time it's called. So you end up with a list containing 3 references to the same `Product`, and that call to `startScraping` is mutating the same product instance each time it's called. You probably want something like `startScraping(new Product())`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Marie , I changed that.

Comment: @canton7 I checked it, but therefore i store it into ```newProduct```. When I ConsoleWrite ```newProduct``` each iteration has the correct Product. But when adding it to the list, it somehow is being overwritten.

Comment: @lightyears99 I tried to explain what your problem is. You don't have 3 distinct `Product` objects in your list: you have three references to the **same** `Product` object -- the same `Product`, referenced 3 times. You access the same `Product` object through `list[0]`, `list[1]` and `list[2]`. Every time `chooseStrategy` is called, it changes that same, single `Product` object

Comment: Okay, I think I get your point thanks, but how do I properly fix that?

Comment: See my previous comment. You need to create **new** `Product` objects each time, rather than constantly changing the same, single object. You create new `Product` objects with `new Product()`

Comment: Thank you, @canton7. It totaly makes sense, but I didnt even think about this. I guess that's what I have to get used to :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be similiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330693/addlast-on-one-list-adding-to-all-lists-in-an-array-of-lists-c-sharp). Don't use a LinkedList if you don't really want to use one. Rather go with the basic list of .net with

```
List<Product>
```

With .Add(item) you can append your list for one item, which seems to be the desired behavior here.

Edit1:
Other approach

```
public static void ScrapeMindfactory(List<string> mindfactoryList)
{
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
ScrapedData data = new ScrapedData();
LinkedList<Product> list = new LinkedList<Product>();

for (int j = 0; j < mindfactoryList.Count; j++)
{
    HtmlRequest req = new HtmlRequest(mindfactoryList[j]);
    html = req.StartRequest(html);
    var newProduct = data.chooseStrategy(new ConcreteStrategyMindfactory(html));

    Console.WriteLine("###" + newProduct.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("###" + newProduct.Price);

    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");

    list.AddLast(newProduct);
    foreach (Product product in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(product.Price);
    }
}
```

in chooseStrategy():

```
    public Product chooseStrategy(ScraperStrategy ConcreteStrategy)
        {
            return ConcreteStrategy.startScraping(new Product());
        }
```

This way it works.

The Reference to the product in chooseStrategy was always the same, therefore, startScraping needs `(new Product())` as parameter.
@canton7

Comment: I have already tried this, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I edited the answer to explain the approach of canton7

Comment: I edited the answer to your approach @canton7. I am not sure if my edit is public yet.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

fix this

```
public Product chooseStrategy(ScraperStrategy ConcreteStrategy)
        {
           var product= new  Product();
            return ConcreteStrategy.startScraping(product);
        }
```

or even better

```
public override Product startScraping()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConcreteStateMindfactory");

         var  product = new Product {

        Name = this._html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[6]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/h1")[0].InnerText, // Name xPath

           Price = this._html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[6]/section/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]")[0].InnerText // Price xPath

}

            return product;
        }

public Product chooseStrategy(ScraperStrategy ConcreteStrategy)
        {
           
            return ConcreteStrategy.startScraping();
        }
```